# Frame based animation on WP7 Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation

Coming from the iOS world where we have UIImageView and the property animationImages:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages

Where animationImages is just an array of arbitrary animation frames. You specify the images (maybe 15), then set the total animation time (maybe 4 seconds) in one of the other properties, then just start the anim and the images in animationImages will play sequentially over the specified time with an even frame rate.

How would I do the same with WP7/Silverlight? This all Expression Blend seems wonderful, but I just can't find a way to animate the image source (I'm guessing it might be impossible). How would I do the same? Should I add a unique image object for each frame in the animation, then play around with visibility/opacity properties and manually have to create all the spaced out key frames? That sounds like a lot of extra work + overhead and not a nice way to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually animate the Image.Source property here's a tutorial.

[Animating Images in WP7](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone-7/tutorials/candle)

Comment: Perfect. So it's not possible in Expression Blend after all. I would surely put a designer in front of Expression Blend because it's so easy to animate values of objects and thus create animations. But creating "Disney" like anims with a couple of frames means you have to touch code and I assume that most of designers would never want to touch Visual Studio. :-P

Comment: I haven't actually tried to replicate the storyboard using Blend so not entire sure if its possible.

Comment: Fine, you found one specific example where iOS provides better designer support. Do you think this statement has a general validity? For example does iOS allow the designer to re-skin the control, improve the state animations, add the transitions? If so, does iOS support any animations or does it have some limitations as well? Just asking...

Comment: Uhhh... what I wrote about iOS, that process is 100% done in code. I have never found out a way to do animations with a graphical tool designed for iOS (I always did anims in code so far). I don't think Interface Builder can do that. I didn't try to find out of course. The iOS environment isn't bad but a quick look at the WP7 environment (well, VS + Blend) and it's easy to see that it's the more robust one.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Animations-in-depthndash-Overview-and-Getting-Started

http://www.wearerighteous.com/wp7-development/xaml-animation-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7/

http://www.windowspresentationfoundation.com/?p=712

Try out these links. Especially the first one, I think the first one resolve all you doubts. In wp7 we can go for two options either XAML based (static) animations / or with the help of C# code. By using blend u can create all sot of static animation with out any issue. Here the animation is working on the basis of page frames. If u are interested in learning more about Animation try this too;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189019(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Nice pages, although they didn't answer my question.